# Convert vertical list to horizontal table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list in Excel that consists of 3 columns:

```
Reference - Feature ID - Feature Value
A - Size - 42
A - Colour - Green
A - Height - High
B - Size - 43
B - Colour - Red
C - Colour - Red
C - Height - High
```

I would like to transpose this to a horizontal table:

```
Reference - Size - Colour - Height
A - 42 - Green - High
B - 43 - Red - (blank)
C - (blank) - Red - High
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Excel VBA?
The values will consist of text and numbers, so I can't use a simple pivot (I think)
The format won't always be the same either, this simple example uses Size, Colour and Height but it should work dynamically.

I've been looking for a solution to this for a while now, but without success.
I always end up with solutions for the other way around (from the table to a list) :-)
Any help will be highly appreciated :-)

Comment: You could get a list of unique references, find the max number of rows for any reference which will give you the number of items per row and then loop through each, probably best to put into an array. It would be good if you posted your own effort.

Comment: How about range copy/paste transpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with Power Query (*available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365*):

- Group by Reference
- Pivot each "grouped" table with no aggregation

To use Power Query:

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***EDIT:** Code modified to account for varying `Feature ID`'s*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4_2"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Reference", type text}, 
        {"Feature ID", type text}, 
        {"Feature Value", type text}}),
        
//get List of all possible Columns
//could sort these if you want, or place in some specified order
    colNames = List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Feature ID]),


//group by reference, then pivot each "sub-table" and expand
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Reference"}, {
        {"Pivot", each Table.Pivot(_,[Feature ID],"Feature ID","Feature Value")}
        }),
    #"Expanded Pivot" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Pivot", 
                                                    colNames,colNames)    
in
    #"Expanded Pivot"
```

[image]